# Percona Cluster - Master node failed, how to proceed

Tags: mysql, percona, galera

I have a 5 node Percona Galera Mysql Cluster.

The True Master node and a slave died (server went off) and i assume, now one of the slave nodes is master, i checked their state (website turned off) and they are all in sync and not changing, i want to start back up the master node and it regain its "master-ish" status AND get the updated data which made be a few hours old.

This is an active High-Transactional Database so data is 100% important.

Can I start up the master normally, or should/could i copy the data from an updated slave and paste it in the master? (i know where everything is).

Whats the best course of action?

Comment: i am not understand. if you use galera cluster there is NO master node. every node in the cluster can act as master an every node has the same info. How many node you have in the cluster ? and how many are crashed ? if a node comes back it automatic a member in the cluster. it syncs the date and is online

Comment: 5 Nodes, i mean master as in the node you bootstrapped, im looking to 100% avoid split brain  AND data loss, and my understanding is a master-master replication is really a master-slave with a buffer of time and data.

Comment: if you want you can call me, the we can talk about your problem and only put the result here. i hope my english is good enough. where are you from ?

Comment: I would love that, how do i call you?

Comment: in my profile :-) email: buffen@t-online.de Phone: +49 2163 5719653

Comment: do you have skype? I could email you for more info.

Comment: sorry not installed on this mac, but you can send me your phone number then i will call you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some stuff from MariaDB

> MariaDB Galera Cluster is a synchronous multi-master cluster for MariaDB. It is available on Linux only, and only supports the
>   XtraDB/InnoDB storage engines (although there is experimental support
>   for MyISAM - see the wsrep_replicate_myisam system variable).
>
> Starting with MariaDB 10.1, the wsrep API for Galera Cluster is
>   included by default. This is available as a separate download for
>   MariaDB 10.0 and MariaDB 5.5

**Features**

> - Synchronous replication
> - Active-active multi-master topology
> - Read and write to any cluster node
> - Automatic membership control, failed nodes drop from the cluster
> - Automatic node joining
> - True parallel replication, on row level
> - Direct client connections, native MariaDB

**look & feel Benefits**

The above features yield several benefits for a

> DBMS clustering solution, including:
>
> - No slave lag
> - No lost transactions
> - Both read and write scalability
> - Smaller client latencies

And it works perfect with **MaxScale** a DB Proxy.

Here also a Overview from FromDual its not the newest, but you can see the work of Galera very good.

https://www.fromdual.com/sites/default/files/galera_fromdual_cm_2013.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have 5 nodes cluster and 2 died you still have quorum and that means your cluster is still active and can service query.
All the nodes should be in sync so you can make any of the active node as master and also re-boot your failed nodes.
(there is no concept of master but master above means you can get your application to point to this as primary node).

If there isn't much activity on the active nodes (cluster) then failed nodes would do an IST to catch-up. If the there is too-much of activity which means write-sets are no more available in active-nodes gcache then SST would be done.

Comment: Concepts like master-slave and master-master have no relation here. Those are async replication terms and you are not using async replication. You are using PXC which is synchronous. As mentioned above, there is no concept of "master" or "slave" in PXC. All nodes are equal. All nodes can accept writes and all nodes remain in sync with each other. When you bring up the failed hosts, just start them normally (ie: don't bootstrap). They will rejoin the cluster and sync any changes that may have happened on other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

One *can* treat Galera as Master + N-1 Slaves.  But you lose some of the uptime if the designated Master dies -- as you found out.  There are some 'valid' reasons for using such a configuration, but it is normal to treat all nodes as read-write, in which case the death of one will go almost unnoticed.

If you can simply reboot the dead master, it will communicate with the other nodes and probably do a quick IST to repair the data.

If you have to replace the dead Master with a fresh box, there will need to be a SST to load the data.  That is automagic; you do nothing (or virtually nothing).  Since the SST takes an amount of time proportional to the amount of data, this could take a long time.  *You should not copy the data yourself.*

It would have been better if you had a plan for routing writes to another node when the Master dies.  This would probably lead to the least disruption of the overall system.

Another choice is to change the IP address of a node to fool the clients into thinking it is the old Master.

Yet another thought is to use a Proxy (MaxScale, HAProxy, etc) in front of the 5 nodes, and reconfigure it to establish the new Master node.